# Popover tableview with dynamic array data

Tags: copy, nsarray, mutable, popover

I am trying to reuse the popover tableview code such that when the user touches the Canada button, the provinces of Canada (Alberta, British Columbia, ...) are displayed; when the user touches the USA button the states of USA (Alabama, Alaska, ...) are displayed. The problem is when I hit the USA button after the Canada button, the first 12 states of the USA are not displayed by the 13 provinces/territories of Canada are still displayed.

I am following the code here

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial

but modifying the setColorButtonTapped code to take an array so I can reuse the code for different arrays

```
- (IBAction)setColorButtonTapped:(id)sender withData:(NSArray *) data {
    if (_colorPicker == nil) {
        self.colorPicker = [[[ColorPickerController alloc] 
                             initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease];
        _colorPicker.delegate = self;
        self.colorPickerPopover = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] 
                                    initWithContentViewController:_colorPicker] autorelease];               
    }
    [self.colorPickerPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender 
                                    permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
_colorPicker.tableList = [data copy];
// I defined a property NSMutableArray *tableList
// I think the problem is with the way I copy the data  }
```

Sorry about the fomatting of the code.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Joe

Answer (score 0):

Joe, I'm guessing many will tell you to be a bit more specific. Nonetheless, one thing that caught my eye is that you don't seem to empty your `.tableList` anywhere on this code snippet.

Basically, try checking whether it has data or not before you copy new one into it. If it does, remove the old data and copy the new one.